# error in query using MySQL and PHP, based on showing data from database

Tags: php, mysql

code:

```
<!-- content -->
<article id="content" class="tabs">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box2">

        <?php 
            //session_start();  
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `db`.`news` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 20";
            include 'php/dbconnection.php';
            $conn = OpenCon();  //$conn=$_SESSION['conn'];
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

            if($result){
                $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

                echo "<div class='wrapper tab-content'>";
                echo "<section class='col1'>";

                echo "<h4><span>" . $rows['date']. "</span> </h4>";
                echo "<p class='pad_bot2'><strong>". $rows['title']. "
</strong></p>";
                echo "<p class='pad_bot1'>".$rows['des'] ."</p>";

                echo "</section>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        ?>
        </div>

     </div>

</article>
<!-- /content-->
```

Here I'm trying to, print 'news' table from database, but I'm unable to print anything on webpage.
can anyone point out, what is wrong in this ?
Thank You in advance for any help!

Comment: make the connection to db, before the sql select.

Comment: yes did, yet no output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For commented `$conn=$_SESSION['conn'];`

You cannot store resource handles within a `$_SESSION`. See [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php):

> Some types of data can not be serialized thus stored in sessions. It
>   includes resource variables or objects with circular references (i.e.
>   objects which passes a reference to itself to another object).

As your object contains the connection link it can't be serialized, Just reconnect with every request.

And you can make clean template like below

```
<!-- content -->
<article id="content" class="tabs">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box2">
        <?php 
            //session_start();  
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `db`.`news` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 20";
            include 'php/dbconnection.php';
            $conn = OpenCon(); 
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            if($result):
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)):
         ?>
           <div class='wrapper tab-content'>
             <section class='col1'>
                <h4><span><?php echo $row['date'];?></span></h4>
                <p class='pad_bot2'>
                   <strong><?php echo $row['title'];?></strong>
                </p>
                <p class='pad_bot1'><?php echo $row['des'];?></p>
            </section>
           </div>
        <?php
           endwhile;
           else:
        ?>
        <p>No active news</p>    
       <?php
           endif;
       ?>
        </div>
     </div>
</article>
<!-- /content-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `mysqli_fetch_row($result)` inside a loop.

Example with your case:

```
if($result){
    while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

        echo "<div class='wrapper tab-content'>";
        echo "<section class='col1'>";

        echo "<h4><span>" . $rows['date']. "</span> </h4>";
        echo "<p class='pad_bot2'><strong>". $rows['title']. "
        </strong></p>";
        echo "<p class='pad_bot1'>".$rows['des'] ."</p>";

        echo "</section>";
        echo "</div>";
    }

}
// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

// Numeric array

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
```

// Associative array

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

So for your code, you need to change:

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

to:

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Also, you should check for number of rows before fetching by using:

```
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Only if `$rowcount` is more than 0, you should `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Comment: Hope you aren't making any typos with `$row` and `$rows`, Also, `echo` the query, execute it in your MySQL client and check if it really has some output.